# Reload page without <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to render a page without executing it's JavaScript (however inject my own script), showing the user how the page would look from a bot's POV.

So far I have thought of loading the page using ajax, removing all `<script></script>` tags from the loaded data, injecting my own `<script></script>` tags and replacing page html with the filtered data.

Are there any better ways of achieving this?

Comment: I am sorry I have answered quickly.. but what exactly did you need?

Comment: If you're going to load it with ajax, I'm assuming it's on your own server and you have full control and can just remove the script tags, otherwise use the serverside to get the page contents and filter out any javascript ?

Comment: @Prasanth what part do you need me to clarify?

Comment: @adeneo It's not my own server, the I'm writing a browser plugin

Comment: @RobFox you should consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659351/removing-all-script-tags-from-html-with-js-regular-expression

Comment: Why don't you try with commenting script tags on window load?

Comment: The question is not how to remove script tags using JS, it's trivial. The question is more about the method in general, or if there is much simpler way I'm overlooking.

Comment: Interesting and related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463406/disable-javascript-in-curl-request-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not a better way, but an alternative to using javascript to do what you want:

You can write a (php) server-side script, use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the original page contents, use php to remove and replace javascript page contents ([str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [substr_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)) then call this php script in an iframe.

See my related answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17262334/888177

Comment: Hmm.. This would also remove cookies and clear user session which is nice.

Comment: Why more costly?  Also in my experience it is normally better to let the server handle most computations and manipulations, if at all possible.  And once you have create the script your page HTML is drastically simplified.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

[Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

**EDIT:**

So, here's something you can do:

Check out this jquery plugin called [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

What it does is, load remote url content into a neat popup div on the page. You can check if you can modify it's code to make it work how you want.

Also quick headsup: bots don't have cookies as well. So, stripping just script tags won't do. Also have to disable cookies in the request.

Comment: You can also check out some sites like: http://responsive.is/ http://ami.responsivedesign.is/

Comment: Even though this may not exactly answer the question, I still found this answer quite useful, as an option to at least keep in mind when you need to load a page with alternative content.